# Matching variations of a String using a single RegEx

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift

Is it possible to check for multiple variations of a string using a **single** Regular Expressions?

I want find matches of the following two string variations in a longer string.

- yearly
- every year

E.g.

- "Do some clean up *every year*"
- "Plan *yearly* clean up"

Currently my regex pattern looks like the following, working only for one specific variation

```
    var pattern = "yearly"
    var error: NSError?
    var regularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!
    let matchingItems = regularExpression.matchesInString(entryString, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, countElements(entryString)))
```

Can the matching of both cases ("yearly" + "every year") be combined using one Regular Expression or do I need two separate Regular Expressions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pattern = "yearly|(?:every year)"
```

You can try this way using `|` or operator.

Comment: Nice answer but an explanation of the non-capturing parentheses would help. ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)